# Should using the programming language in the title be edited out if they already have it as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, title

So, I ran crossed a post that had the title somewhat like "Javascript - Converting 0.517034 to 0.517" (keep in mind it's an example).  He already tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) in his question.  When I suggested and edit to remove the "Javascript -" out of the title, the edit was denied.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: I see no such rejected suggestion on your account, which suggests the post was probably bad enough to end up quickly deleted (or it happened a while ago and I didn't look far enough back...)

Comment: @Woobie the question was deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're just editing a tag out of the title, the edit is not substantial enough to *suggest.*

Wait until you have editing privileges, then you can make these kinds of edits yourself, without approval.  Better yet, fix all of the problems you find with a post, not just the tag in the title.

Comment: I had suggested multiple edits to the user, he denied them all, then edited it himself (I think). I even left a comment questioning.  But he later deleted the question.

Comment: @Xero: In individual edits? You're getting a bit greedy with the 2 rep earns, aren't you?

Comment: He kept rejecting them, so I keep suggesting them.

Comment: Yeah, you're doing it wrong.  The OP has the final say on suggested edits, so if you can't get it approved, just move on.

Comment: Alright, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't edit words out of titles just because they appear in tags. Question titles appear in many contexts without the tag.

“No tags in titles” means that we don't want titles like “[javascript] [float] [convert] [0.517] Converting 0.517034 to 0.517”. It doesn't mean that words that appear in tags are superfluous in titles.

A title like “Javascript - Converting 0.517034 to 0.517” is a lot more useful than “Javascript - Converting 0.517034 to 0.517”. We prefer titles that flow naturally, like “Converting 0.517034 to 0.517 in Javascript”, but “Javascript - Converting 0.517034 to 0.517” isn't horrible.

Think of the title as the one thing that you'll see when searching for a question. Converting 0.517034 is too specific for a good title. A better title would be “Round a number to 3 decimal places in Javascript”. Do keep “Javascript” since it's a critical aspect of the question — a similar question about a different programming language would have completely different answers.

Comment: I just don't see the point of putting the programming language into the title, when I can see "javascript" as a tag in the question.

Comment: @Xero There are many places where titles are displayed without tags. Even on the SO questions list, tags are displayed in a smaller font, so the information from the title is what is most visible.